# Unable to get intent sent from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-viewholder

I have a `Service` which looks for changes in database and then notify users based on certain factors. One such `notification` has an action button by clicking on which a `BroadcastReceiver` is triggered and `Activity.class` gets opened.

Here's how:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public MyBroadcastReceiver(){
            super();
        }

        @Override 
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

             if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(getString(R.string.broadcast_id_for_rating))) {
                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
                resultIntent.putExtra("abc", "abc");
                resultIntent.setType("text/plain");
                resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(resultIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Intent is null.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's how I'm trying to receive intent in a `ViewHolder` class called from this `Activity.class`:

```
public class RModelClass extends AbstractItem<RModelClass, RModelClass.ViewHolder> {

    public RModelClass() {}

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return R.id.recycler_view_r;
    }

    @Override
    public int getLayoutRes() {
        return R.layout.r_played;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(final RModelClass.ViewHolder holder, List payloads) {
        super.bindView(holder, payloads);

        String abc;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            openForRating = intent.getExtras().getString("abc");

            if (abc != null) {
                Log.d("abc", "YO!!");

            } else {
                Log.d("abc", "NO!!");
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("null", "INTENT!!");
        }
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }

    }

}
```

**The problem is** that I'm getting `D/null: INTENT!!` logged out and unable to receive the intent.

**Please help** me why is this happening and how to get the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `getApplicationContext()` in `BroadcastReceiver` to create Intent .

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("abc", "abc");
resultIntent.setType("text/plain");
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Also you are doing mistake in this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

this is new intent object and you are trying to get values from this `Intent` object.

you must get Intent from your Android Component like `getIntent()`

if you are in `Fragment` Class or in `Adapter` then use `getActvity().getIntent()` and `((Activity)context).getIntent()` respectively for `fragment` and `Adapter`.

Comment: I tried `getIntent()` but I'm getting `Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()'` warning. I tried this way too: `holder.itemView.getContext().getIntent()` but got the same warning.

Comment: if you are in Fragment Class or in Adapter then use getActvity().getIntent() and ((Activity)context).getIntent() respectively for fragment and adapter.

Answer (score 0):

> why is this happening

You create a brand-new `Intent` object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

Then you try looking for extras on that brand-new `Intent` object:

```
if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
```

That `Intent` object is brand-new. It will not have any extras.

> how to get the intent?

To get the `Intent` that was used to create the activity, call `getIntent()`.

Comment: I tried `getIntent()` but I'm getting `Cannot resolve method 'getIntent()'` warning. I tried this way too: `holder.itemView.getContext().getIntent()` but got the same warning.

Comment: @HammadNasir: `getIntent()` is a method on `Activity`. The activity that creates this UI needs to pass that `Intent` into your `RModelClass`, or at least into its `bindView()` method.